# icons from wingding 3 fonts wont display on andoid 13

Tags: c#, maui, glyph, wingdings

I'm trying to draw arrows on button with wingding 3 font, fonts added in resources, registered in mauiprogram.cs, but on android 13 platform icons don't appearing, but on Android 8 all working correctly, how to correct this?

here is my code:

mauiprogram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiMTAdmob()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        fonts.AddFont("WINGDNG3.TTF", "WingDing");
    });
```

XAML code:

```
 <Button Grid.Row="5"
         Grid.Column="2"
         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
         BorderColor="Transparent"
         Command="{Binding NextbuttonactionCommand}"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         ImageSource="{FontImageSource FontFamily='WingDing',
                                       Glyph='&#xF08e;',
                                       Color={Binding ScreenColor,
                                                   Converter={StaticResource colorInverter}}}">
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
         <VisualStateGroupList>
             <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                 <VisualState Name="Normal">
                     <VisualState.Setters>
                         <Setter Property="Button.BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                     </VisualState.Setters>
                 </VisualState>
                 <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                     <VisualState.Setters>
                         <Setter Property="Button.BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                     </VisualState.Setters>
                 </VisualState>
             </VisualStateGroup>
         </VisualStateGroupList>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 </Button>
```

[Android 13 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLVia.png)

and

[Android 8 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIvhI.png)

Comment: Have you tried other icons of the wingding3 font? Will such a problem also arise?

Comment: Could you please post the `WINGDNG3.TTF` you used so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT,  [WINGDING3.TTF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1thI_h9CqJT211hczF4aKYb2ufVyuqhwv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Based on your code and the `ttf` you shared, I could reproduce this problem.  For this, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).  Thanks for your support and feedback.